# How to find the probability of drawing certain cards by certain turns?

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

I've been playing a ton of Marvel Snap lately. It's a card game with simple rules. You have 12 cards in your deck. You start with 3 cards and draw 1 card every turn for the 6 turns you play. This means that you draw 9 cards by the end of the game.

What I'm having trouble with is the chance of drawing combinations of cards by different turns. For example, let's say I want to draw Spider-Man by turn 4 and Miles Morales by turn 5. Say there's a combo play that requires me to play Spider-Man by turn 4 and Miles Morales by turn 5, so I have to draw them by those turns. I know that I have a 58.33% chance (7/12) of drawing Spider-Man by turn 4, and a 66.67% (8/12) chance of drawing Miles Morales by turn 5.

How do I find the chance of both events happening? I feel like simply multiplying the two probabilities together ignores edge cases, but is that how I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of syntax, label the cards A,B,C,...,J,K,L.

You want the probability of drawing A by turn 4, and (simultaneously) B by turn 5.

The probability is $~\dfrac{7}{12}~$ that A is one of the first $~7~$ cards.

There are a variety of ways of formally completing the problem.  I will use two methods.

You are interested in the probability of also drawing a B by turn 5, given that you drew an A by turn 4.

---

$\underline{\text{Method 1}}$

**Warning**

This method, while valid, does not generalize well.

The only way to fail in drawing a B by turn 5, is if the B is one of the last $~4~$ cards, out of the $~11~$ cards remaining, given that the A was one of the first $~7~$ cards.

So, the probability of drawing the A by turn 4 and the B by turn 5 is

$$\frac{7}{12} - \left[ ~\frac{7}{12} \times \frac{4}{11} ~\right] $$

$$= \frac{7}{12} \times \left[ ~1 - \frac{4}{11} ~\right] $$

$$= \frac{7}{12} \times \frac{7}{11} = \frac{49}{132}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Method 2}}$

Let $~E_1~$ denote the event that you draw the A on or before the 1st 4 turns.

Let $~E_2~$ denote the event that you draw the B on or before the 1st 5 turns.

You want to compute

$$p(E_1) \times p(E_2 ~| ~E_1). \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the second factor represents the probability of event $E_2$ occurring **given** that event $E_1$ has occurred.

As discussed, $~p(E_1) = \dfrac{7}{12}.~$

To compute $~p(E_2 ~| ~E_1), ~$ **assume** that event $~E_1~$ has occurred and then ask yourself how that assumption has affected whether event $~E_2~$ will also occur.

In consideration of event $~E_2~$ by itself, without any regard for whether event $~E_1~$ has occurred, you would be presuming that you have a $~12~$ card deck, and you want to know the probability that the B is one of the first $~8~$ cards.

Under the assumption that event $~E_1~$ is one of the first $~7~$ cards, the circumstances in the previous paragraph have changed in two ways:

- With the A occurring somewhere in the first $~7~$ card positions, there are only $~(8-1) = 7~$ remaining positions that the B can satisfactorily occur.
- With the A occurring somewhere in the first $~7~$ card positions, in your attempt to receive the card B soon enough, you are (in effect) battling an $~11~$ card deck, since the A has been eliminated from consideration.

Therefore,

$$p(E_2 ~| ~E_1) = \frac{7}{11} \implies p(E_1) \times p(E_2 ~| ~E_1) = \frac{7}{12} \times \frac{7}{11}.$$

---

**Addendum**

This section is added purely as a sanity check.  I strongly suspect that the problem composer intended that Method 2 above be used.

There are two ways of succeeding in getting the A and B in a timely manner.

- You get the A in the first 7 cards, and then get
  the B specifically on card 8. 
  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{7}{12} \times \frac{1}{11}.$
- You get both the A and the B in the first $~7~$ cards. 
  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{12}{2}}
   = \frac{7 \times 6}{12 \times 11}.$

Summing the two **mutually exclusive** cases give you

$$\frac{[~7 \times 1 ~] + [~7 \times 6 ~]}{12 \times 11}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this game, and hope that I have understood your question correctly, so far.

The probability of drawing Spider-Man (SM) by turn $4$ is $P(\text{SM},4)=7/12=58.33\%$.

The conditional probability of drawing Miles Morales by turn 5, given that you've already drawn Spider-Man.

Now keep in mind, that by turn $4$, you have drawn $4$ cards, one of which is Spider-Man. There remain 8 cards in the deck, including Miles Morales (MM) and I get: $P(\text{MM},5)= 1/8$.

Now, I just multiply the probabilities together: $P=(7/12) * (1/8) = 7/96 ≈ 7.29\%$. This must be the probability of drawing Spider-Man by turn $4$ and Miles Morales by turn $5$.

Comment: So that makes sense, but I'm also able to draw Miles Morales before / on turn 4. How do I take that into account? Edit: also by turn 4, I would have drawn 7 cards no? Since I start with 3.

Comment: In addition to the difficult represented by the comment of @Lachino, directly above, you also have a second difficulty.  Under the assumption that Spider-Man has been successfully drawn in time, you are then trying to draw Mike Morales from an $~11~$ card deck.  If you assume that you are required to draw Mike Morales precisely on draw 5 (which is a false assumption), then the probability of drawing Mike Morales (on specifically draw 5) would be $~\dfrac{1}{11}.$